# How can I change the header of my page when someone logs in?

Tags: php, html, session

I am making a website which allows users to login. I have a header design which have login and password fields in it. I have included it in all other pages. 
Now when someone logs in, the page header should display the welcome message and logout button etc.

I have a `header.php` and `loged_header.php` for the different headers.

Comment: Use if/else condition?

Comment: I think you mean to use session variables.

Comment: Use conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if/else condition.

Because you are using PHP, you can use something called `include`.

For example:

```
 <div id="header">
 <?php
      if(loggedIn){
           include 'loged_header.php';
      }else{
           include 'header.php';
      }
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I checked if $_SESSION[uname] is set or not.